# Jetpack navigation component throws an IllegalStateException when loading a start destination with nullable argument

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-navigation

I added a nullable argument to my start destination:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/nav_graph"
        app:startDestination="@id/startDest">

    <fragment android:id="@+id/startDest"
          android:name="com.myapp.MyStartFragment"
          android:label="Start"
          tools:layout="@layout/fragment_start">
        <argument
            android:name="dataObject"
            app:argType="com.myapp.MyDataObject"
            android:defaultValue="@null"
            app:nullable="true"/>
        ...
    </fragment>
    ...
</navigation>
```

But when I load my app, I get the following exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment MyStartFragment{a4ffd1f (ca52d4dc-ff36-4a93-8ebf-f11af7b7d5aa) id=0x7f080145} has null arguments
    at com.myapp.MyStartFragment$$special$$inlined$navArgs$1.invoke(FragmentNavArgsLazy.kt:42)
    at com.myapp.MyStartFragment$$special$$inlined$navArgs$1.invoke(Unknown Source:0)
    at androidx.navigation.NavArgsLazy.getValue(NavArgsLazy.kt:44)
    at androidx.navigation.NavArgsLazy.getValue(NavArgsLazy.kt:34)
    at com.myapp.MyStartFragment.getArgs(Unknown Source:27)
    at com.myapp.MyStartFragment.onAttach(MyStartFragment.kt:85)
```

And the exception is triggered by this piece of code in MyStartFragment:

```
private val args: MyStartFragmentArgs by navArgs()
override fun onAttach(context: Context) {
    super.onAttach(context)
    val title = if(this.args.dataObject == null) getString(R.string.start_list_title) else this.args.dataObject!!.name
    ...
}
```

And here is the code for MyDataObject:

```
@Parcelize
data class MyDataObject (
    val id: String,
    val name: String,
    val externalIdentifier: String
    val type: MyDataEnumType,
    var responsibleUser: SomeOtherParcelableClass?
): Parcelable
```

What I don't understand is that my start destination doesn't get passed arguments properly by the navigation controller. Am I missing something here?

Comment: Could you have a look into possibilities to attach `MyStartFragment` manually? From your code you posted it should work.

Comment: What do you mean by attaching it manually?

Comment: The exception states that `arguments` is null. Since navigation components takes care of setting these, there might be a place where you create the fragment differently. Calling the constructor without setting any arguments or some configuration you omitted.

Comment: But that's the thing: the navigation component is supposed to set those arguments, and it does so in other fragments where I navigate after using actions. But for some reason, either because of a bug in the navigation component, or indeed a missing configuration, it fails to do it in this case.

Comment: Have you tried an unstable version of the library? I implemented your example with version `2.1.0-rc01` and everything worked fine.

Comment: Can you post you `MyDataObject ` class?

Comment: @tynn I just tried to use the latest version of the navigation component (2.2.0-alpha01) but now I have compilation errors everywhere I try to use navArgs(): Cannot inline bytecode built with JVM target 1.8 into bytecode that is being built with JVM target 1.6. Please specify proper '-jvm-target' option. And yet I set sourceCompatibility and targetCompatibility to 1.8 in my compileOptions.

Comment: @BlackHatSamurai I added it to my question

Comment: Can you post the Fragment you are trying to pass the data to @Sebastien

Comment: The fragment I'm trying to pass the data to is MyStartFragment. It is both a start destination and a target destination for an action that comes from another fragment. When it is loaded as a start destination, the argument should be null. And when it is loaded from another fragment, this other fragment will pass a non-null value into the argument.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hello I am assuming you want to achieve something like below

```
BeforeFragment --arg--> StartFragment --> AfterFragment
```

[image: sample nav graph]

This flows are similar first time user, returning user flows. Here `BeforeFragment` is last fragment in `login_nav_graph` nested graph. `StartFragment` is the starting destination of `main_nav_graph`. `StartFragment` is the first screen returning user sees.

So in `BeforeFragment` you may set args as follows

```
val userJohn:User = User(34, "John", 645, UserType.TYPE2, Guardian("Mike"))
val action = BeforeFragmentDirections.actionGlobalStart(userJohn)
findNavController().navigate(action)
```

and in `StartFragment` you may do following as you already did

```
title = if(this.args.user == null)
   getString(R.string.user_name) // mocks loading saved user name
else
   this.args.user?.name // when user is first time user read from passed args
```

Sample Repo can be found [here](https://github.com/kaushalyap/so-navargs)

---

**My best guess**

This issue is due to bug in older navigation version, so use `2.2.0-alpha01` which is I am using in the sample repo.

In order to fix errors that occurs when moved to new navigation version
in you module gradle file add following

```
android {
    ...
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8" // set your Java version here
    }
}
```

This fixes the error

> Cannot inline byte code ...

---

**Keep in mind passing complex objects as arguments is not recommended.** Quoting from [docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-pass-data).

> In general, you should strongly prefer passing only the minimal amount
>   of data between destinations. For example, you should pass a key to
>   retrieve an object rather than passing the object itself, as the total
>   space for all saved states is limited on Android. If you need to pass
>   large amounts of data, consider using a ViewModel as described in
>   Share data between fragments.

If this fixes your issue please confirm the answer, since I spent lot of time preparing this post.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That fixed my issue.

Comment: I was using version 2.0.0 for passing a nullable string as argument and I was getting the same complaint as in the title. After updating to 2.1.0 and adding the kotlinOptions bit, the error went off. Thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 2):

If you create a fragment with a bundle, but without NavController.navigate, and you still want to keep "by navArgs()" in destination fragment e.g because you want to use it in launchFragmentInContainer when testing, then use try/catch. The IllegalStateException is thrown before you start checking nullable type.

```
private fun updateArguments(){
    this.title = try{
        val args: DestinationFragmentArgs by navArgs()

        if (args.dataObject?.name == ""){
            // default value provided so check whether bundle was used
            arguments?.getString("name") ?: ""
        }else {
            args?.venueId
        }
    }catch (ex: Exception){
        // fragment created without using NavController.navigate
        arguments?.getString("venueId") ?: ""
    }
}
```

Room is very fast, so retrieving an object from the id as an argument should not be an issue, so try using primitive types for your arguments if possible, otherwise use Parcelable or Serialize for inexpensive objects.